# Python3 CSV reader ValueError

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I searched through the python csv questions, can't seem to find anything addressing the reader error I'm getting.

I have a csv file with 6 columns, trying to access two of them:

```
import csv

with open('/home/conjugater/Downloads/aapl.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  dialect=csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
  csvfile.seek(0)
  reader=csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
  for row in reader:
      for Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume in row:
          print(Date, Close)
```

I'm not done coding, but this is my first time using the csv module and I'm just trying to get a feel for it (relatively new to python in general).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "reader.py", line 8, in <module>
for Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume in row:
ValueError: need more than 5 values to unpack
```

I can get the columns I want with

```
for row in reader:
    print(row[0], row[4])
```

but I know there's a way to assign each column a name with python as well; any help much appreciated.

Comment: looks like your file has only 5 columns.

Comment: @dano print(len(row)) returns 6 for every row

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 for loops when you only need one:

```
for (Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) in reader:
    print(Date, Close)
```

Comment: I think he probably wants `for (Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) in reader:`. But yeah, that's his problem.

Comment: true, kinda new to python (and programming in general), not yet as efficient as I'd like to be.  Thanks for pointing that out, I'm trying to develop efficient coding practices

Comment: @bushc Not sure if you realized this or not, but this is the actual cause of your error. Doing `for Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume in row:` like you are is actually iterating over each  of the six elements in the `row` tuple one at a time.

Comment: @dano does that slow things down? not sure I understand why that's a bad thing?

Comment: @bushc It means that right now, you're doing this: `for Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume in ("6/12/15", "20.00", "21.00", "19.00", "20.58", "20"):` Which is **not** what you're actually trying to do. That will iterate through the tuple, taking each element, and trying to unpack it to `Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume`. So first it will try to unpack `"6/12/2014"`, which will of course fail, and cause the `ValueError` you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assigning `newline=''`? That tells `open()` to treat each empty string as the end of a line. Try this instead: `newline='\n'`. Or try it without passing `newline`.

Vor's comment below is useful too. [See docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) on `open` for more information.

Comment: @Vor https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html says to use newline='' for file objects

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you need to use

```
with open('/home/conjugater/Downloads/aapl.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  dialect=csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
  csvfile.seek(0)
  reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect, fieldnames = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
  for row in reader:
      for Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume in row:
          print("{}: {}".format(Date, Close))
```

Hope that helps....

Comment: thanks, I'll check that out after I try @dano 's fix